# Property 'do' does not exist on type AngularFireList

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I have seen many other posts like this, but I still am not understanding what the problem is and how to fix it.

```
posts$: Observable<Post[]> = this.db
    .list(`posts/${this.uid}`)
    .do(next => this.store.set('posts', next));
constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private authService: AuthService
) {}
```

This is the error that I get:
`Property 'do' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<{}>`

Here are my imports:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AuthService } from '../../../../auth/shared/services/auth/auth.service';

import { Store } from '../../../../store';
```

Finally here are the dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

Comment: Did you try using `pipe` and `tap`?

Comment: Some things changed in rxjs 6. Please check the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

Comment: This could be helpful too https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/186

Comment: @TimMartens just a quick thank you - your link helped me to figure out how to fix everything and get it working. My updated code is below in case anyone stumbles upon this post and can use it to help themselves sort their issues.
`posts$: Observable<Post[]> = this.db
    .list<Post>(`posts/${this.uid}`)
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(tap(next => this.store.set('posts', next)));`
note we now typecast list and use pipe and tap to accomodate updates to firebase and rxjs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post I just did with working code.

[error: Property 'getChildren' does not exist on type 'DataSnapshot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667824/error-property-getchildren-does-not-exist-on-type-datasnapshot/51668117#51668117)

```
Also new/correct way for referenceing rxjs

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Old incorrect way
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: Had a look at your answer and im unsure what needs to change in order to get things working

Comment: I made some adjustments and have the following error now:
`Type 'Observable<Post[] | AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<{}>>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Post[]>'.`