# Typescript and rxjs 6 - Property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm developing a small app with Ionic 3 querying a firebase db to get 2 series of data. The first build fail with error "Property  does not exist on type '{}'" but if I save one more time the .ts file (save for ex. home.ts so that ionic rebuild) the error disappear and the page works.

I'm doing:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

  this.db.list('myPath-in-firebase', ref => ref.orderByChild('my-key'))
    .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(result => { 
      let mydata1= result.map(x => x.my-property-key1);
      let mydata2= result.map(x => x.my-property-key2);
      console.log(mydata1);
      };
}
```

but I get a typescript error: "Property 'my-property-key1' does not exist on type '{}'" in the first ionic serve build start, then I save a file of the project, ionic rebuild and it works fine.
I guess that I have to declare x and his properties somewhere but I cannot know how and where.

Finally (maybe there is a better method and you could help me?), my DB is like so:

```
my-firebase-database
    |- my-Path
           |- Push-ID-1
                   |- my-property-key1: value
                   |- my-property-key2: value
           |- Push-ID-2
                   |- my-property-key1: value
                   |- my-property-key2: value
           |- Push-ID-3
                   |- my-property-key1: value
                   |- my-property-key2: value
```

I would have 2 array, one containing values of my-property-key1 and the other with my-property-key2 values. 
Thanks for helping

**Update**:
See in comments. At the moment I was using a workaround changing syntax from result.map(x => x.my-property-key1) to result.map(x => x[my-property-key1])

according to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12596

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm remove --save typescript;
npm i --save-dev typescript@2.6.2;
npm i --save-dev rxjs@6.2.2
npm i --save-dev rxjs-compat@6.2.2



import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here as well the subscription is structured a bit differently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667824/error-property-getchildren-does-not-exist-on-type-datasnapshot/51668117#51668117

Comment: rxjs and rsjs-compact should be dependencies and not dev dependencies

Comment: Thanks all, my packages versions are ok and imports too. Trying to export class and declare variable don't do the job but I'm pretty sure it depends on my incapacity. Finally I solved changing syntax from result.map(x => x.my-property-key1) to result.map(x => x[my-property-key1]) ... Hope this can help other people too